# Spring Mvc- delete user from database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm developing small Spring MVC application, and I have a problem with delete customer from mysql database. When I delete customer like a admin, customer disappears only in the customer table and remains in the authority and users tables. The question is how to repair it?

User.class

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int usersId;
private String username;
private String password;
private Boolean enabled;
private int customerId;


public int getUsersId() {
    return usersId;
}

public void setUsersId(int usersId) {
    this.usersId = usersId;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Boolean getEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

public int getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}

public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}
```

}

```
@Entity
```

public class Authorities {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int authoritiesId;
private String username;
private String authority;

public int getAuthoritiesId() {
    return authoritiesId;
}

public void setAuthoritiesId(int authoritiesId) {
    this.authoritiesId = authoritiesId;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getAuthority() {
    return authority;
}

public void setAuthority(String authority) {
    this.authority = authority;
}
```

}

```
@Entity
```

public class Customer implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5140900014886997914L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int customerId;

@NotEmpty(message = "Nazwa użytkownika nie może pozostać pusta!")

private String customerName;

@NotEmpty(message = "Uzupełnij adres email!")
private String customerEmail;
private String customerPhone;

@NotEmpty(message = "Nazwa użytkownika nie może pozostać pusta!")
private String username;

@NotEmpty(message = "Uzupełnij hasło!")
@Size(min = 6, max = 16, message = "Hasło musi zawierać od 6 do 16 znaków!")
private String password;

private boolean enabled;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JoinColumn(name = "billingAddressId")
private BillingAddress billingAddress;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JoinColumn(name = "shippingAddressId")
private ShippingAddress shippingAddress;

@OneToOne( cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, mappedBy = "customer")
@JoinColumn(name = "cartId")
@JsonIgnore
private Cart cart;



public int getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}

public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}

public String getCustomerName() {
    return customerName;
}

public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
    this.customerName = customerName;
}

public String getCustomerEmail() {
    return customerEmail;
}

public void setCustomerEmail(String customerEmail) {
    this.customerEmail = customerEmail;
}

public String getCustomerPhone() {
    return customerPhone;
}

public void setCustomerPhone(String customerPhone) {
    this.customerPhone = customerPhone;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

public BillingAddress getBillingAddress() {
    return billingAddress;
}

public void setBillingAddress(BillingAddress billingAddress) {
    this.billingAddress = billingAddress;
}

public ShippingAddress getShippingAddress() {
    return shippingAddress;
}

public void setShippingAddress(ShippingAddress shippingAddress) {
    this.shippingAddress = shippingAddress;
}

public Cart getCart() {
    return cart;
}

public void setCart(Cart cart) {
    this.cart = cart;
}
```

}

```
@Controller
```

public class RegisterController {

```
@RequestMapping("/register")
public String registerCustomer(Model model) {
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    BillingAddress billingAddress = new BillingAddress();
    ShippingAddress shippingAddress = new ShippingAddress();
    customer.setBillingAddress(billingAddress);
    customer.setShippingAddress(shippingAddress);

    model.addAttribute("customer", customer);
    return "registerCustomer";
}

@Autowired
private CustomerService customerService;


@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerCustomerPost(@Valid @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer, BindingResult result,
        Model model) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "registerCustomer";
    }

    List<Customer> customerList = customerService.getAllCustomers();

    for (int i = 0; i < customerList.size(); i++) {
        if (customer.getCustomerEmail().equals(customerList.get(i).getCustomerEmail())) {
            model.addAttribute("emailMsg", "Email już istnieje w bazie danych!");

            return "registerCustomer";
        }

        if (customer.getUsername().equals(customerList.get(i).getUsername())) {
            model.addAttribute("usernameMsg", "Użytkownik o dane nazwie już istnieje w bazie!");

            return "registerCustomer";
        }
    }


    customer.setEnabled(true);
    customerService.addCustomer(customer);
    return "registerCustomerSuccess";
}
```

}

```
@Repository
```

@Transactional
public class CustomerDaoImpl implements CustomerDao {

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void addCustomer(Customer customer) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    customer.getBillingAddress().setCustomer(customer);
    customer.getShippingAddress().setCustomer(customer);

    session.saveOrUpdate(customer);
    session.saveOrUpdate(customer.getBillingAddress());
    session.saveOrUpdate(customer.getShippingAddress());

    Users newUser = new Users();
    newUser.setUsername(customer.getUsername());
    newUser.setPassword(customer.getPassword());
    newUser.setEnabled(true);
    newUser.setCustomerId(customer.getCustomerId());

    Authorities newAuthority = new Authorities();
    newAuthority.setAuthority("ROLE_USER");
    session.saveOrUpdate(newUser);
    session.saveOrUpdate(newAuthority);
    newAuthority.setUsername(customer.getUsername());

    Cart newCart = new Cart();
    newCart.setCustomer(customer);
    customer.setCart(newCart);

    session.saveOrUpdate(customer);
    session.saveOrUpdate(newCart);

    session.flush();

}

public Customer getCustomerById(int id) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Customer customer = (Customer) session.get(Customer.class, id);
    session.flush();

    return customer;
}

public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Customer ");
    List<Customer> customerList = query.list();

    return customerList;

}

public Customer getCustomerByUsername(String username) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Customer where username = ?");
    query.setString(0, username);

    return (Customer) query.uniqueResult();
}

public void deleteCustomer(Customer customer) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.delete(customer);
    session.flush();

}
```

}

Comment: The code where you delete the user would be more useful than the entity.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add foreign key constraints between tables and set action as(on delete= cascade).

Comment: Between table users and customers? How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your customer entity doesn't have any relationship with user and authority tables, then no delete is performed by jpa. 
**EDIT**
In customer entity instead of username you could have

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="username", cascadeType=CascadeType.REMOVE) private User user
```

The same for Authories entity:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="username", cascadeType=CascadeType.REMOVE) private User user
```

Comment: What kind of relationship should I apply? Between which classes or tables?

Comment: I can't remove username from customer class, because it is necessary in registration process

Comment: You don't remove username, you just encapsulate it in User object via OneToOne relarionship.

Answer (score 1):

On your opinion ,the relationship between User and Customer is one to one.And you want to delete User when you delete the Customer .

First we have to  explicit the relationship.

In the User Entity , i suggest you to remove the CustomerId , And add User user to Customer Entity.

And the Customer Entity will be :

```
private User user;
public void setUser(User user){
   this.user = user;
}
@OneToOne
public User getUser(){
   return this.user;
}
```

After that ,you can get the User by customer(userId),And when you want to delete the Customer ,you should get the User first,then delete Customer and delete that User

Comment: And what about modifications in other classes?